# Show original message on click, inline, for chat replies

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chat

When somebody replies to an older message in chat, you have to click the "in reply to" arrow and jump to the message to get the context. That makes you leave the current position in the transcript, and old content possibly even needs to be loaded first. That's often a bit disrupting, especially when you're reading through the transcript.

[Discourse](http://www.discourse.org) has a nice "inline quoting" feature. When you reply to a post, you see a "in reply to" button:

[image]

When you click it, the original message is opened inline:

[image]

Would something like that make sense for chat? It would be much more minimalistic of course, just fading in the original message above the reply button. Here's a (sloppy) sketch what it could look like:

[image]

Comment: If you have the [chat userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat), you can left-arrow on a message selected with the keyboard navigation to preview the replied-to message. `</self-promotion>`

Comment: @J.Steen well, *some* amount of that is expected and normal - especially when it comes to features that many people want, but the developers don't want to integrate into the core for some reason.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, I know. I still find it amusing, but my perception is a bit skewed (which is why I removed the comment). =)

Answer (score 4):

I agree that something like this would be a nice feature.

Unfortunately, we aren't really focusing on chat at the moment. Immediate priorities are top bar, localization, mobile apps, finishing SSL, and updating the log in/register process with SSL improvements.

I'll keep this on the list for when chat comes back on our radar, though.

Comment: Excellent, that leaves time to collect a list of other chat-things I like to complain about.